# Mysql left join with concatination?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables which look like this

```
contacts
-------------------------------------------------------
| id | fname | lname | email | address | uid | uniqid |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

```
numbers
---------------------
| id | pnumber | cid |
---------------------
```

This is my Sql Code

```
SELECT * FROM contacts LEFT JOIN numbers ON contacts.uniqid = numbers.cid
```

The uniqid is the same as cid, my problem is when i am trying to left join these two tables it returns this
[image: "]
Note: Sorry had to use an image because when i try to use text it breaks

I want to get all the pnumbers in a single column without repeating. Is there any way to achieve this or should i use php?

**Expected results**

```
id, fname, lname, email, address, uid, uniqid, id, pnumber,pnumber,pnumber, cid
```

Comment: Please show your expected output. As you can see in your image, the `pnumbers` is repeating, but the `id` (third column from right to left) is unique, so we don't know which `id` you want to keep.

Comment: You have to know that using `LEFT JOIN` means that if you have repeated value in the table on the left, it will show all. That being said, you can try a simple checking on your left table by executing this query `SELECT uniqid,count(*) FROM contacts GROUP BY uniqid` to see if there is any `uniqid` count value more than 1. If there is, it's not that unique after all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `group_concat()` with `distinct`

```
SELECT contacts.id, fname, lname, email, address,uid,uniqud,
group_concat(distinct pnumber order by pnumber),cid
FROM contacts LEFT JOIN numbers 
ON contacts.uniqid = numbers.cid 
group by contacts.id, fname, lname, email, address,uid,uniqud,cid
```

Comment: `group by id` is ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) statement and [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function

```
SELECT 
  contacts.* 
  GROUP_CONCAT(numbers.pnumber)
FROM contacts 
LEFT JOIN numbers ON contacts.uniqid = numbers.cid 
GROUP BY contacts.id, contacts.fname, contacts.lname, contacts.email, contacts.address, contacts.uid, contacts.uniqid
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use DISTINCT to filter the duplicates:

```
SELECT DISTINCT pnumber FROM contacts LEFT JOIN numbers ON contacts.uniqid = numbers.cid
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This --

```
SELECT c.*, GROUP_CONCAT(n. pnumber SEPARATOR ', ') FROM contacts as c LEFT JOIN numbers as n ON c.uniqid = n.cid 
    GROUP BY c.id, c.fname, c.lname, c.email, c.address, c.uid, c.uniqid
```